# Is it possible to include the line no and filename in nestjs + typeorm when SQL error occurs?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

If there is an SQL error occurs, the call stack only trace back to something like

```
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
at PoolConnection.query (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
at MysqlQueryRunner.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/src/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.ts:155:36)
at step (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:133:27)
at Object.next (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:57)
at fulfilled (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nestCms/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
```

Any clue on how to quickly identify which line and file is actually sending the query from?

Comment: How are you logging the error? Please show us the code

Comment: I just call the query builder and execute something stupid. The QueryFailedError is coming from nest itself from my understanding. Just want to know if it can show something like at fileA.ts on line 1

fileA:
const stupid = await manager.createQueryBuilder(Whatever, 'hello')...getMany(); // something wrong in the sql